# Sharing Answered Questions

Tags: discussion

I need help asking better questions.

### Simple but Real Questions

When I figure out *seemingly* simple questions, should I answer the question myself or leave it for others?

1. [Use for identification Category Setting?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1824/46)
2. [Reindexing Search in 2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1886/46)

### Design Validation Type Questions

I often have design questions soliciting technical expertise. For example:

1. [Reviewing or Logging Publish Transaction Failures](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1884/46) (Event System approaches)
2. [Inform Authors of Scheduled Publishing](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1801/46) (GUI performance and Publishing Queue)
3. [Is it useful to show which version of an item is published, and if so, how should I do this?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1881/46) (Event System question checking if I missed something)

**Should I answer questions I find myself or put them up for someone else to answer?**

**Are "Is this approach sound?" type questions okay?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found your '*seemingly* simple questions' very interesting (I hadn't really noticed `Use for identification` until I saw your question).  However, listening to the Stack Exchange podcasts, one of the main things that they highlight is that they want the answers on Stack Exchange to be the best answer on the internet (for that question).

If you found the answer very easily and well explained elsewhere, then I would suggest that it is easy for someone else with the same question to find the answer there too.  Therefore, I would suggest that these questions do not need to be asked on the Tridion Stack Exchange site.

However, if you had to do some investigation across multiple locations, or some investigation of your own, then this probably would be a good question to ask and then self-answer.  I would be reluctant to ask questions here as a pop quiz.  If you know the answer, or suspect that someone could enhance/clarify it, then I would recommend asking and self-answering.

It is often very useful to read "IS this approach sound?" type questions, as it can help everyone to improve method/patterns for doing common tasks.  I would say that these too are acceptable as long as they fully define the scope of the problem, fully document any investigation/findings that you have already done and can have a definitive answer.

[The Help section](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) says that we should try to avoid chatty, open-ended questions or ones that have no right answer (e.g. "What is your favourite ____ ?").  However, I think that this leaves a gap in the community now that the old forums are read only.  Individual blog post are very interesting, but do not really attract much conversation, and they are spread across multiple sites.  I am not proposing that we resurrect the forums, but I think that somewhere for any 'chatty' questions may useful to ensure that the Tridion Stack Exchange site stays clean.  All ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Thanks, this helps! I've found that answers to even "easy" Tridion answers aren't available anywhere public, so I'll definitely post the Q *and* A if relevant. I may struggle with the approach-type questions--after defining the scope and doing research I'll often end up with a non-question or something that's already answered. :-) I'm thinking Linked-In might be a good spot for surveys, opinions, and chatty questions.